# Upload file usinng ASP.Net Web API and Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to upload an image file using ASP.Net Web API and Ajax.
I have enabled Cors in my controller as

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
    public class myController: ApiController
    {
```

Also this is the method to upload the image

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [ActionName("PostUserImage")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostUserImage()
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            try
            {

                var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);

                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                    {

                        int MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 1; //Size = 1 MB  

                        IList<string> AllowedFileExtensions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png" };
                        var ext = postedFile.FileName.Substring(postedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                        var extension = ext.ToLower();
                        if (!AllowedFileExtensions.Contains(extension))
                        {

                            var message = string.Format("Please Upload image of type .jpg,.gif,.png.");

                            dict.Add("error", message);
                            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dict);
                        }
                        else if (postedFile.ContentLength > MaxContentLength)
                        {

                            var message = string.Format("Please Upload a file upto 1 mb.");

                            dict.Add("error", message);
                            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dict);
                        }
                        else
                        {



                            var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Userimage/" + postedFile.FileName + extension);

                            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                        }
                    }

                    var message1 = string.Format("Image Updated Successfully.");
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, message1); ;
                }
                var res = string.Format("Please Upload a image.");
                dict.Add("error", res);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, dict);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var res = string.Format("some Message");
                dict.Add("error", res);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, dict);
            }
        }
```

here is my Ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btnUploadFile').on('click', function () {

                var data = new FormData();

                var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files;

                // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
                if (files.length > 0) {
                    data.append("UploadedImage", files[0]);
                }

                // Make Ajax request with the contentType = false, and procesDate = false
                var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://link to my controller method",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: data
                });

                ajaxRequest.done(function (xhr, textStatus) {
                    // Do other operation
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is the error I am getting all the time when I try to upload image. Been struggling with it for days. Please help

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://my controller method. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I have also enabled cors in WebApiConfig as

```
config.EnableCors();
```

Comment: Do you have your WebAPI application separated from the client application?

Comment: @Jeric Cruz: **multi page image**? what is that?

Comment: If your WebAPI is hosted on a different domain, CORS need to be enalbed. You can check this URL https://enable-cors.org/ for more info about how to enable CORS. Important thing is that the browser makes a prefly request with OPTIONS verb, check if this verb is enabled on your server.